# Check if following multiplication table represents a group or not?

Tags: group-theory

Does the following Group multiplication table correspond to a group $\{e,b,c\}$

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & e & b & c\\
\hline
e & e & b & c\\
b & b & e & c\\
c & c & b & e
\end{array}$$

It can be easily seen that It is closed under *, identity element $e$ exists, each element has its inverse i.e $e^{-1}=e$, $b^{-1}=b$ and $c^{-1}=c$.

For associativity I have checked $9= (6+3)$ possible combinations and haven't found any contradiction. **So I think it is a group**

> Am I Correct??

Comment: No.
What did you check when you checked associazivity?

Comment: The third column seems suspicious to me with its 2 $c$'s

Comment: @miracle173 I checked combinations like $e*(b*c)$,$ c*(e*b) $ to see if I can find some contradiction like $c*(b*e) $ is not equal to $(c*b)*e$

Comment: @Somos I have started learning Group theory by myself, So Can you please explain what makes this not a group by 4 axioms.

Comment: In a group there is canceling rules, but $ec=bc$ multiplying with $c^{-1}$ from the right won't work.  Similar for $eb=cb$.

Comment: But you didn‘t Check all possible combinations. The combination containing e will always be associativ, if e is the idendity element. The interesting ones are that not containing e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(c\ast b)\ast b = b\ast b = e$ and $c\ast (b\ast b) = c\ast e = c$, associativity is not given.

Answer (score 3):

A group multiplication table is a *Latin square*. This means that there are no repeats in a column or row. This table has repeated elements in the same column/row, so it is not a group.

Proof:

Assume the multiplication table represents a group. Suppose that there is a repeat in the same row. If the row is the $x$ row, and the repeats are in the $y,z$ columns in that row, then $xy=xz$. Since we have a group, $y=x^{-1}xy=x^{-1}xz=z$, so they are actually in the same column, i.e. they are not really a repeat. If the repeat is in the same column instead, the proof is very similar.

In particular, here the middle column has repeats $eb=b$ and $cb=b$. So, $e=ebb^{-1}=cbb^{-1}=c$ using the group axioms of associativity, identity and inverses. But $e\ne c$ so we have a contradiction.

Comment: Can we prove that this is not a group by those 4 group axioms?